# Get very first element of a multi bracket list in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

If I have a list as follows:

```
(((X)))
```

I want to get just `X` and not get the brackets

In LISP, if I do `CAR`, I'll still get the brackets.

Is there any function that can do this for me?

Answer (score 6):

In Common Lisp, `( some-value )` is a list with a single element, given by `some-value`.

The classical graphical representation of lists shows that in effect a single value list is a “cons” (pair) of pointers to `some-value` and `nil`:

[image]

so that gettting the `car` of it produces `some-value`, while the `cdr` produces `nil`.

So, what is the meaning of this s-expression: `((x))` ? If you substitute `some-value` in the first example with `(x)` you obtain exactly this. That is, this is not a “multi-bracket list”, but just a list with a single element which is itself a list with a single element (in other words, a list in which the car is a single-element list). And this can be shown graphically as in the next figure:

[image]

So that this time to get `x` you have to use `car` twice, writing `(car (car list))` (actually this can be abbreviated in Common-Lisp with `(caar list))` (see the [reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm)).

I left to you to complete the exercise, to draw the diagram that correspond to `(((x)))`, and to find how to extract `x` from this list.

Comment: how do you create this pretty graphics?

Comment: @sds, I use an old version of OmniGraffle on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, for instance:

```
(defun first-atom (c)
  (if (consp c)
    (first-atom (first c))
    c)))
```

This is slightly wrong because `(first-atom 1)` is not an error and it probably should be: it needs an outer check for a cons which calls a recursive local fn to do the work.  Bit you get the idea.

---

Sorry about the possibly botched indentation: hard to get right on a phone.